# Why objects are to be created in calling some functions

Tags: java, android-studio, google-geocoder

In the Geocoder.java class there is the below method

```
 public List<Address> getFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude, int maxResults)
        throws IOException {
        if (latitude < -90.0 || latitude > 90.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("latitude == " + latitude);
        }
        if (longitude < -180.0 || longitude > 180.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("longitude == " + longitude);
        }
        try {
            List<Address> results = new ArrayList<Address>();
            String ex =  mService.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults,
                mParams, results);
            if (ex != null) {
                throw new IOException(ex);
            } else {
                return results;
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getFromLocation: got RemoteException", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here `getFromLocation` is the member function of the class. So to call this function can't we simply call that as `List<Address> address = Geocoder.getFromLocation(//the required parameters)`. I know this won't work and to make it work we need to create an object of Geocoder class. So can anyone please explain why the object creation is necessary, I am bit confused as I had seen in some cases functions are called by directly using their class names

Comment: You should already have an instance somewhere. Otherwise calling the method doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user207421 Then what about like Math.sqrt(). We call it directly from the math class. Could you please explain why